# Coloured partitions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, set-partition

I have $2n$ elements, $n$ of which are blue and the other $n$ are orange. Other than sharing a colour, they are distinct, i.e. each of those $2n$ objects is different and recognizable from any other.

#### How many partitions are there such that in each subset there’s at least one blue element *and* there are at least two elements total?

So, for example, a *good* partition would be {blue_1, blue_2} or {blue_1, orange_1} or {blue_5, orange_1, orange_3, orange_7} and a *bad* (i.e. the one I don’t want counted) one {blue_1} (because there’s only one element), or {orange_3, orange_11} (because there’s no blue one).

---

I tried to approach this first by starting with Bell number and subtracting, but that lead me nowhere. Then I started anew, trying to get a recurrence relation.

Obviously, $X_2 = 1$, because the only partition one can get is {blue_1, orange_1}.

Then, if I already had $X_{2n - 2}$ partitioned, I could:

1. Keep things as-is and add a new pair as another subset—one option for each previous partition.
2. Add {blue_n, orange_n}, as a pair, to any pre-existing subset—the number of subsets for each partition; *but I don’t know how many those are*.
3. Add {blue_n} to one subset and {orange_n} to another—and again, while I know it’s $\binom{x}{2}$ for each partition with $x$ subset, I don’t know how to write that in a useful way.
4. Some other solutions, created by taking blue_n and adding pre-existing oranges to it (because now it can create a valid partition)—but here I am not even sure how much *that* would be, maybe somewhere around $B_{2n - 2}$?

---

I have created a [small Python script](https://gist.github.com/Althorion/5d3180b2f9453b911e9c36b006191017) to calculate a few first values. It shows $X_2 = 1, X_4 = 3, X_6 = 28, X_8 = 433, X_5 = 9461$. Unfortunatelly, there’s [no such sequence](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C3%2C28%2C433%2C9461) on OEIS.

Answer (score 0):

The recurrence relation you describe won't quite work, for the reasons you describe above -- you don't know the size of each case. Instead you can consider the following cases: One set has exactly one blue element, and each set has at least 2 blue elements. To make it easy, first we'll say that the sets of the partition are distinguishable, then divide by 2 at the end (this way was more intuitive for me, but the direct counting works as well; you just have to be careful in the third step below). Call the sets Set $A$ and Set $B$.

If set $A$ has exactly one blue element, there are $2^n - 1$ ways to choose orange elements for set $A$ (we can choose any nonempty subset). There are $n$ ways to choose the blue element, for a total of $n(2^n-1)$ instances in this case. Note that set $B$ is determined by the contents of set $A$.

Similarly, there are $n(2^n-1)$ ways for set $B$ to have exactly one blue element.

In the other case, each set has at least $2$ blue elements. We need to choose somewhere between $2$ and $n-2$ blue elements to go in set $A$. There are $2^n - 2 - 2n$ such subsets (we can choose any subset, except for the empty set, the entire set, any singleton set, or any set of size $n-1$). Then we can choose any subset of the orange elements in $2^n$ ways, for a total of $2^n(2^n - 2 - 2n)$ ways.

Summing these, we have $2n(2^n - 1) + 2^n(2^n - 2 - 2n)$ such partitions; we need to divide by $2$ to account for ordering the sets $A$ and $B$ to get: $n(2^n-1) + 2^n(2^{n-1} - 1 - n) = 2^{2n-1} - 2^n - n$.

Comment: If I’m not wrong, that assumes bi-partition of a set (i.e. partition into exactly two sets), but that’s not the only partitions I care for. For example, for $n=3$, I consider $\{\{B1, O1\}, \{B2, O3\}, \{B3, O2\}\}$ (and other five similar tri-partitions) to be as valid as $\{\{B1, B2, O1\}, \{B3, O2, O3\}\}$ etc.

Comment: Ah, I misread the question. I’m not sure I have a good approach for your actual problem.